# How to configure site to site VPN between Cisco ASA and Cisco router?

Tags: cisco, vpn, cisco-ios, ipsec, cisco-commands

I have CISCO ASA on one site and CISCO ROUTER on other side, both have outside interface facing public IP and doing NAT for internal VLAN's. How to connect different VLAN's on one site to VLAN's on other site with IPSEC site to site VPN?

Comment: This is a big question with a lot of information and I do not think someone would help you with.

You should do some researches and then try to configure the tunnel yourselves. If it is not working, share your configuration and discuss with us here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How to connect different VLAN's on one site to VLAN's on other site with IPSEC site to site VPN?

This is a big question with a lot of information.

You can read my blog post at the following link for sample configuration. You should try to configure the tunnel yourselves and share your configuration if it still does not work.

http://netlabbuilder.net/cisco-ios-site-to-site-ipsec-ikev1-vpn-tunnel-with-cisco-asa/